# Quick store, lookup and retrieve database design

Tags: python, mysql, database, nosql

all!

I'm struggling with this. I have a crawler that runs my network to retrieve all live IP addresses and stores them on a table. Another service runs all the records on the table to update the status of the machines. The read and write access might be simultaneous.

These are the fields that I need to store. As you can see, it's quite simple.

1 - The IP address is the PRIMARY KEY, so I it won't duplicate machines. (I can change it to the MAC address)

2 - Timestamp of first contact

3 - Timestamp of last contact

4 - Response of the last contact (boolean)

I'm thinking about using MySQL, but then it might come with an overhead. Already thought about using a flat text file, but the parsing would add up to the python scripts I already have.

Is there any database solution that can fit my problem?

Thank you all!

Comment: `stores them on a table` ? What is a `table` in this context?

Comment: Sorry. A database table. Not sure if using RDBMS is the right way...

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at sqlite - it might be just what you're looking for and it's much lighter than mysql.